# Conics, rational points and probability

Tags: nt.number-theory, rational-points

Given a conic $Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2+Dx+Ey+F=0$ with integers and random coefficients, what is more probable? To find a rational point on the conic or not?

Comment: It depends on the distribution on integers.

Comment: @fedor The standard way to order is as a six tuple of of rational numbers treated as a point in projective space ordered by height.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For any given prime number $p > 2$ the probability that there is no $p$-adic point is $\ge c/p$ for some constant $c > 0$ indpendent of $p$. Since the sum over $1/p$ diverges, this implies that the `probability' (or rather, density) of conics with a rational point is zero.

EDIT: I assume that the `probability' is meant in the sense of density, i.e.
$$ \lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{\#\{(A,B,C,D,E,F) \in ({\mathbb Z} \cap [-N,N])^6 : \exists \text{ rational point}\}}{(2N+1)^6}. $$
The probability of $p$-adic solubility (with respect to the standard measure on ${\mathbb Z}_p^6$) comes down to the $p$-adic density of pairs of $p$-adic integers $a, b$ such that the Hilbert symbol $(a,b)_p = -1$.
This is the case (e.g.) when $v_p(a) = 1$, $v_p(b) = 0$ and $b$ is a nonsquare mod $p$; the probability for this is $\frac{p-1}{p^2} \cdot \frac{p-1}{2p} \ge \frac{2}{9p}$.

EDIT 2: I realized that the map that produces $a,b$ from $A,B,C,D,E,F$
very likely does not preserve $p$-adic measure. So here is an alternative
and more direct argument. We work with projective coordinates, as
suggested by Joe Silverman. By Hensel's Lemma, the non-existence of a
smooth ${\mathbb F}_p$-point on the reduction mod $p$ of the conic
is a necessary condition for the non-existence of $p$-adic points,
and this is also sufficient when the conic is regular over ${\mathbb Z}_p$.
So whenever the reduction mod $p$ is the product of two conjugate and
distinct linear forms with coefficients in ${\mathbb F}_{p^2}$ *and*
the intersection point of the two corresponding lines is regular,
then there is no $p$-adic point on the conic. The $p$-adic measure
(as a subset of ${\mathbb P}^5({\mathbb Q}_p)$) of the corresponding
set is
$$\frac{1}{2} \frac{\#{\mathbb P}^2({\mathbb F}_{p^2}) - \#{\mathbb P}^2({\mathbb F}_p)}{\#{\mathbb P}^5({\mathbb F}_p)} \frac{p-1}{p}
 = \frac{(p-1)^2}{2(p^3+1)} \ge \frac{3}{14p} .$$
(The factor $(p-1)/p$ is the probability that the intersection point
is regular.) The paper by Bhargava, Cremona, Fisher, Jones and Keating
linked in post.as.a.guest's answer gives the precise value $p/(2(p+1)^2)$.

Comment: Thanks Michael Stoll. Why the constant $c$ is independent of $p$?

Comment: It is more than $c/p$ for the natural measure on $p$-adics. But there is no probabilistic measure on integers which is uniform modulo any prime.

Comment: @MichaelJoyce : thanks, I've fixed the omission.

Comment: It would seem to be more natural to restrict to 6-tuples with $\gcd(A,B,\ldots,F)=1$, since the quadratic form is determined by the homogeneous coordinates $[A,B,\ldots,F]$. Certainly this is the right thing to do if one wishes to generalize from $\mathbb Q$ to a number field. Of course, this won't affect your conclusion that the density is 0.

Answer (score 13):

Problems of this type are considered by Serre in the paper:

Serre - Spécialisation des éléments de $\mathrm{Br}_2(\mathbb{Q}(T_1,\ldots, T_n))$

The case relevant to you is Exemple 4. Here Serre shows that

\begin{align*}
&\#\{|A|,|B|,|C|,|D|,|E|,|F| \leq N : \\
& Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2+Dx+Ey+F=0 \text{ has a rational point} \} \ll \frac{N^6}{(\log N)^{1/2}}.
\end{align*}

This gives a more precise quantitative version of "probability $0$" mentioned by Michael Stoll.

Hooley has in fact shown that Serre's bound is sharp. This result is the object of the paper:

Hooley - On ternary quadratic forms that represent zero II.

Answer (score 3):

There is a paper, that answers this in more generality.

https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~taf1000/papers/isotropic.html

In your case, the probability is 0 (asymptotically) under conditions that the distribution is piecewise smooth and rapidly decaying, though likely can be generalized, in your case.

Comment: The linked paper is definitely helpful.